# PrimeNG - Steps: how to get the current step highlighted

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'm trying to use the [steps](http://primefaces.org/primeng/steps/personal) to display several steps in a wizard.

My wizard steps works, but I can't manage to have the current steps highlighted properly in the steps list.

I was able to replicate in a small stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eujcl2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsteps%2Fstep-two%2Fstep-two.component.html

When I run my code, I got basically this:

[image: enter code here]

But in their demo, the current step gets highlighted:

[image]

Any idea what is going on? The styles are imported, I to bind an "activeIndex", but when I move, the step doesn't.

Comment: fix your routes as mentioned below. That makes it work as you expected. In the ngOnInt(){} of the wizard component change the routerLink to match your steps components routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routes are not matching with what you have defined app route file vs what you have listed in wizard.component.ts, i.e.

```
// Your routes
{ path: 'step-1', component: StepOneComponent },
{ path: 'step-2', component: StepTwoComponent }

// But your step routeLinks
{
    label: 'Step 1',
    routerLink: '/setup/mongDb',
    icon: 'fa-light fa-database',
},
{
    label: 'Step 2',
    routerLink: '/setup/auth-token',
},
```

Once they match, the highlight starts working.

```
this.items = [
      {
        label: 'Step 1',
        routerLink: 'step-1',
        icon: 'fa-light fa-database',
      },
      {
        label: 'Step 2',
        routerLink: 'step-2'
      },
    ];
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zqtstu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fwizard%2Fwizard.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fsteps%2Fstep-one%2Fstep-one.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fwizard%2Fwizard.component.html)

[image]

Comment: Damned, I just saw that I've a typo in my path in my prod env. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

from what I see in your code, you don't use the proper routes.

The buttons trigger `step-1` and `step-2` but your step component is declared with `/setup/mongDb` and `/setup/auth-token` so I think the PrimeNg component doesn't see that you are on the declared path. I didn't look at the source code but I think this could be it.